# setupController no longer working for Ember route

Tags: ember.js

I can not longer setup a route that has a hash of multiple models. What I use to do is this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

  model() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      products: this.store.findAll('product'),
      suppliers: this.store.findAll('supplier')
    });
  },
  setupController(controller, model) {
    controller.set('products', model.products);
    controller.set('suppliers', model.suppliers);
  }

});
```

When I do this I can't loop through each `{{#each products}}` but I still can with `{{#each model.products}}`

Comment: What does console.log(model) in setupController print?

Comment: Not sure if you noticed, but this info would be crucial to resolve your issue.

Comment: If I console.log(model) inside the setupController method, I get my full model properties, including products and suppliers.

Comment: I would expect `each products` to work, and `each model.products` not to work because you never actually set the model on the controller.

Comment: Could you check if that's the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object proxying is deprecated, so you should refer to your models with a `model.` prefix.

The correct way to do this would be to leave out your `setupController` and use the model as an object with `.products` and `.suppliers` keys on it.

You'll still have to `{{#each model.products as |product|}}` unless you want to alias them in your controller like this:

```
products: Ember.computed.alias("model.products")
```

I'd recommend sticking with `model.products` in your template though to alleviate any confusion as to where that particular data came from. Removing it would imply it's controller-related vs. model data fetched in the route's `model` hook.

**EDIT**: The above solution was done in Ember 1.13.5 and should also work in any 2.x version.